# How to Vertically concatenate two two-dimensional array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

This public function receives two two-dimensional arrays of integers as parameters. It returns a new array containing the data of the two arrays received as a parameter "stacked" one above the other. The number of rows of the table returned will therefore be the sum of the number of rows of the two tables received. You can assume that both tables have the same number of columns. In vba and at option base 1

```
Function StackArrays(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim numCols As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    
    numRows = UBound(arr1, 1) + UBound(arr2, 1) 'Calculate total number of rows
    numCols = UBound(arr1, 2) 'Number of columns is the same for both arrays
    
    ReDim result(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols) 'Create result array
    
    'Copy data from the first array into the result array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
            result(i, j) = arr1(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Copy data from the second array into the result array
    For i = UBound(arr1, 1) + 1 To numRows
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2, 2)
            result(i, j) = arr2(i - UBound(arr1, 1), j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    StackArrays = result 'Return result array
End Function
```

but I couldnt make it work when I tested

Comment: Give an example of what you're expected input and output would be.

Comment: I've test with this, working: Sub test()
  Dim result

  Dim arr1(1 To 5, 1 To 3), arr2(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
  
  result = StackArrays(arr1, arr2)

End Sub

Comment: Your second nested loop is still using `arr1` in the `i` loop.

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Range Data

[image]

**Test**

```vb
Sub StackArraysTest()
    With Sheet1
        Dim arr1: arr1 = .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value
        Dim arr2: arr2 = .Range("A7").CurrentRegion.Value
        Dim Data(): Data = StackArrays(arr1, arr2)
        .Range("F2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
End Sub
```

**Function**

```vb
Function StackArrays(ByVal arr1 As Variant, ByVal arr2 As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim r1 As Long, c1 As Long: r1 = UBound(arr1, 1): c1 = UBound(arr1, 2)
    Dim r2 As Long, c2 As Long: r2 = UBound(arr2, 1): c2 = UBound(arr2, 2)
    
    Dim rr As Long: rr = r1 + r2
    Dim cc As Long: cc = Application.Max(c1, c2)
    
    Dim Data(): ReDim Data(1 To rr, 1 To cc)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, dr As Long
    
    For r = 1 To r1
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To c1
            Data(dr, c) = arr1(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    For r = 1 To r2
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To c2
            Data(dr, c) = arr2(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    StackArrays = Data

End Function
```